# FUNCTION <database_name>. TOP does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This message was shown when I used `String sql = "SELECT TOP(1) order_id FROM`orders`ORDER BY order_id DESC; ";`

the data gets updated in the table but the after `String sql = "SELECT TOP(1) order_id FROM`orders`ORDER BY order_id DESC; ";`

the next line of code are not running, I mean the `rs.next()` statements...

I wote my code in JAVA and connecting MySQL via WAMP SERVER.

Comment: `TOP` is a function in SQL Server. It is not available in MySQL. Both are different RDBMS

Comment: So, what should I do to print the last row of the table in MySQL

Comment: Use order by id desc limit 0,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support TOP function. You should use LIMIT, for example:

```
SELECT order_id FROM orders ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @tushar if it worked then will mark the answer as right, please